# Create an array inside of an object containing values from the object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array inside an object containing variables from this object using this but I'm getting an error.
Am I using this wrong ?
Thx for your help

```
var data = {
    p:   [{content: "p",
           text: "this is random text" },
           {content: "p",
            text: "this is a second random text"
         }],
    img: [{content: "image",
           src: "data/img/1_1.png",
           alt: "This a an image"},
          {content: "image",
           src: "data/img/1_2.png",
           alt: "This is the second image"}],
    title: {content: "title",
            text: "Ceci est un titre"},
    //This doesn't work
    all: [this.title, this.p[0], this.img[0], this.p[1], this.img[1]]
}
//But this works
console.log(data.title);
console.log(data.p);
console.log(data.img);
```

Comment: You cannot refer to other parts of an "under construction" object.

Comment: what is the context of `this` in your code? pay attention on this.

Comment: Why store redundant information when you can easily construct the `all` array on the fly?

Comment: It's just easier to build all same elements together in the object because there will be a lot more of them and all is more lisible that way (like 10 data objects named by a numer so reading it like that is more easy I can't create the all array on the fly because it represents the order and it differs considering the page shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` keyword does not point to your current object until it is constructed.

I'm guessing that `this` refers to the next highest scope, or the `Window` object in your case.

A quick test in the browser console:

```
var a = {"test": this};
console.log(a["test"]); //Window
```

You would be better off making that query on the fly when you need the data aggregated that way, or finding a better way to populate that property.